# Ruby - class inheritance and redefining initialize to work with factory methods

Tags: ruby, initialization, temperature

I'm not sure what is happening with the inheritance here. I get a nil value for this code. but when i don't override the initialise method and pass in a hash argument, like the Temperature class accepts (:c => 50) it works fine.

I think that maybe the factory methods are calling the initialize method again which is now changed? but then I would have thought that I get a loop..

thank you. below is the code segment. it's my solution to an r-spec teaching resource

i think my question is:

why is the self.from_celsius method creating a new instance object that doesn't call the conversion method as the initialize method defined in Temperature is supposed to?

```
class Temperature

    ######################## -- getter methods 
    def in_fahrenheit 
        @in_fahrenheit
    end 

    def in_celsius
        @in_celsius
    end

    ######################## -- initialize and call the calculations
    def initialize(hash)
        @options = hash
        conversion
    end

    ######################## -- calculations
    def conversion
        @options.key?(:c) ? @in_fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0*@options[:c].to_f) + 32.0 : @in_fahrenheit = @options[:f]
        @options.key?(:f) ? @in_celsius = (5.0/9.0)*(@options[:f].to_f - 32.0) : @in_celsius = @options[:c]
    end 

    ######################## -- factory methods
    def self.from_celsius(c)
        self.new(:c => c)
    end

    def self.from_fahrenheit(f)
        self.new(:f => f)
    end
end


class Celsius < Temperature
    def initialize(c)
        Temperature.from_celsius(c)
    end
end

class Fahrenheit < Temperature
    def initialize(f)
        Temperature.from_fahrenheit(f)
    end
end


x = Celsius.new(50).in_celsius

puts x.nil?
#=> true
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: question: why is the self.from_celsius method creating a new instance object using the Temperature class as a template, but does not end up assigning values to the class variables

Comment: ive edited to include the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work the way you want:

```
class Celsius < Temperature
    def initialize(c)
        super(c: c)
    end
end

class Fahrenheit < Temperature
    def initialize(f)
      super(f: f)
    end
end
```

You should keep in mind, though, that it's not a good use of inheritance.

The reason your code wasn't working is that initializers aren't supposed to return the newly created object.  The new call creates the object, and the initializer is just initializing it.  Also you should use `attr_accessor` to clean up your getter code.

Comment: thanks. so that basically reformats the initialise arguments into the right format? why wouldn't it have worked before though?

Comment: yeah, that's right.  i'm just calling the initializer you defined in `Temperature`.  it wasn't working before because you weren't calling any code to set `@in_celsius` or `@in_farenheit` on the object being created by `new`.  The initializer was just returning the correct object, but the initializers return value is not what is assigned in the `new` call.  The return value of an initializer is basically ignored.

Comment: except that the Celsius initialize method was calling a Temperature constructor method that was calling the Temperature initialize method with the reformatted arguments. which should have assigned values to the @in_.. variables. I still don't understand why that didn't work

Comment: It was doing what you are saying, but it was doing it on another object.  `initialize` operates on the object being created by `new`.  Inside the initializer you created *another* Temperature object when you invoked the factory method, distinct from the object that was created by new.